# Why does an element of the Galois group of $K(\mu_n)/K$ maps an $n$-th root of unity to another $n$-th root of unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, roots-of-unity, cyclotomic-fields

I am working through [Keith Conrad's article on Cyclotomic extensions](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/cyclotomic.pdf) and have a question regarding the proof in Lemma 2.1.

Let $K$ be any field and $\mu_n \subseteq K^\times$ be the multiplicative subgroup containing all $n$-th roots of unity. We assume $T^n-1$ to be separable over $K$, so $K(\mu_n)/K$ is Galois.

Let $\sigma$ be in the Galois group of $K(\mu_n)/K$ and $\zeta_n$ be a generator of $\mu_n$ (i.e. $\zeta_n$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity). Then $\zeta_n^n = 1$ and $\zeta_n^j\neq 1 $ for all $j$ with $1\leq j <n$.

> **Question**: Next, it is stated that $\sigma(\zeta_n)^n = 1$ and $\sigma(\zeta_n^j) \neq 1$ for all $j$ with $1\leq j <n$. Why is this true?

**My attempt for a proof**

- It is $\sigma(\zeta_n)^n = \sigma(\zeta_n^n) = \sigma(1) = 1$,
- Similarly, we have $\sigma(\zeta_n)^j = \sigma(\zeta_n^j)$. I know that $\zeta_n^j \neq 1$ but how can I exclude the case $\sigma(\zeta_n^j) = 1$?

It would be cool if you could help me explaining this step.

Comment: For $a\in K,\sigma\in Aut(K)$ then $a^n -1=0$ and $a^d -1\ne 0$ for $d< n$ implies that $\sigma(a^n-1)=\sigma(a)^n-1=\sigma(0)=0$ and similarly $\sigma(a)^d-1\ne 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every field homomorphism is injective, so if $\sigma(\zeta_n^j) = 1 = \sigma(1)$, we would have $\zeta_n^j = 1$.